# How to make shared libraries work with python in squashfs (lvm2py and liblvm2app.so)

Tags: python, squashfs

I am trying to write my own script to create partitions. (Even though this can be done in anaconda, I want my custom script) The script creates lvm based partitions using lvm2py module. lvm2py requires liblvm2app library. which I installed in my squashfs.

When my script runs at installation, it is failing saying "LVM Library not found". This is error reported by lvm2py when *find_library("lvm2app")* fails.
Even though liblvm2app.so is present in /usr/lib64/ and all the other libraries dependant on liblvm2app.so are showing resolved in ldd.

Also note that sample python script that does *find_library("c")* also fails. Looks like python is not able to detect any of the shared libraries.

I also tried adding /usr/lib64 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but no luck.

Python is compiled with libpython support.

Comment: Issues resolved. /sbin/ldconfig was not present in squashfs which is used by find_library in ctypes.util. When installed there the library is found by python